# why nav-link class in my code removes my menu items?

Tags: html, django-staticfiles

see when i use nav-link class in navbar. It won't show anything but item is present there. The item which uses nav-link class not visible why ? I share some snapshot see it.Item i am refering to is 'dummy item3'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B2se.png)

Comment: Yahello! Welcome to stackoverflow, your question doesn't clarifies what problem you are facing. please mention your problem properly and what result you want to achieve and what did you tried. share code snippets too so we can help you properly

Comment: I posted a new snapshot, can u please see it and tell me the problem with my code?

Comment: just add `class="nav-item nav-link text-white"` nav-link is making the color transparent......

Comment: How can I add space between them and align them properly? And thanks for your help bro.

Comment: you can use class these classes in parent div `d-flex justify-around` check answer I have attached the snippet there

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet with everything you want. and just a suggestion if you've learned CSS then you should try tailwind CSS it gives alot of customisation than bootstrap.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static food/style.css' %}"> <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
9ndCyUaIbzA12FUVXJ10CjmCapSm075npJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRh002iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous"> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdKrxdiJJigb/j/6851y3Te4Bkz
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark w-full d-flex justify-content-between">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Food-App</a>
<div class="navbar text-white w-50 d-flex justify-content-around">
<a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'food:add items' ">Add item</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="#">Update item</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">dummy item 2</a>
</div>
  </nav></body></html>
```